# How to use spark_read_jdbc in local mode

Tags: sparklyr

I am attempting to develop locally while reading from a MS SQL database with `spark_read_jdbc`. This requires a connection to the database.

I have the following `spark_connect`.

```
library(sparklyr)
# spark_install()
conf <- spark_config()
conf$`sparklyr.cores.local` <- 4
conf$`sparklyr.shell.driver-memory` <- "16G"
conf$spark.memory.fraction <- 0.9

sc <- spark_connect(master = "local", 
                    version = "2.1.0",
                    config = conf)
b <- sparklyr::spark_read_jdbc(sc, 
                                 name ="my_table" , 
                                 options = list(url = "jdbc:sqlserver://<server>", 
                                                user = keyring::key_get("uid"),
                                                driver = "com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver",
                                                password = keyring::key_get("pwd"),
                                                dbtable = "<tablename>"))
```

but when I run the above code I get the following error

> Error: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver

It seems like my driver cannot be found. How can I debug this error.

Comment: did u find a solution to this problem somehow?

Answer (score 0):

It should help. Such as answer on Russian language you could not find it: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/645847/java-lang-classnotfoundexception-com-microsoft-sqlserver-jdbc-sqlserverdriver

Approximate translation from Dmitriy comment:
I have solved this issue by reinstall again sqljdbc4.jar to the lib folder of project and insert again path lib/sqljdbc4.jar to classpath. Also I had moved request execution function to seperate class of project for auxiliary functions and all start work... So just you have to few times on/off the library and all will work.

Answer (score 0):

I think you have to include driver path in spark connection. So include following code into your config **conf$`sparklyr.shell.driver-class-path` <- "driver file path"**